# Swing components not showing when expected

Tags: java, swing, jframe

The aim of the class below is to create a `JFrame` with an `Applet` in each of the `JTabbedPane` tabs. The method `loadPanel()` returns a `Box` component (the supposed "loading screen" which is meant to show while the `Applet` loads), whereas the `loadGame()` method loads and returns an `Applet`.

However when `load()` is called, the `JFrame` shows but the `JTabbedPane` doesn't show up until after the `Applet` loads. Have been racking my brain and not sure what's wrong here, any suggestions appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Loaders extends JFrame {

    int dimension;
    int osClients;
    int rs3Clients;

    public Loaders(int osClients, int rs3Clients) {
        this.osClients = osClients;
        this.rs3Clients = rs3Clients;
        this.dimension = (int) Math.sqrt(osClients + rs3Clients);
    }

    public void load() {

        Loader[] os = new Loader[osClients];
        Loader[] rs3 = new Loader[rs3Clients];

        setTitle("DENCH CLIENTS");
        setSize(768, 528);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new Color(0x2B2B2B));
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        for(int i = 0; i < osClients; i++) {
            os[i] = new Loader(Game.OSRS, i+1);
            tabs.add("OS " + i, os[i].loadPanel());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < rs3Clients; i++) {
            rs3[i] = new Loader(Game.RS3, i+1);
            tabs.add("RS3 " + i, rs3[i].loadPanel());
        }
        add(tabs);
        tabs.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(true);

        for(Loader l : os) {
            System.out.println(l.getWorld());
            int index = tabs.indexOfTabComponent(l.getBox());
            tabs.setComponentAt(index, l.loadGame());
        }

        for(Loader l : rs3) {
            int index = tabs.indexOfTabComponent(l.getBox());
            tabs.setComponentAt(index, l.loadGame());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

Comment: @camickr umm they were...?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). *"umm they were...?"* Some were, others weren't. What @camickr meant was that ***all*** the components should be added before setting the frame visible. And immediately before calling set visible, call `pack()` ..

Answer (score 0):

- move `setVisible` to the end of the method
- No need for `tab.setVisible(true)`
  Since your are updating the tab panels , it is proffered to be called in swing dispatch thread, like this:

  ```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
          for(Loader l : os) {
              System.out.println(l.getWorld());
              int index = tabs.indexOfTabComponent(l.getBox());
              tabs.setComponentAt(index, l.loadGame());
          }

          for(Loader l : rs3) {
              int index = tabs.indexOfTabComponent(l.getBox());
              tabs.setComponentAt(index, l.loadGame());
          }
      }                           
  });
  tabs.setVisible(true);
  setVisible(true);
  }
  ```